# How can I make the bot send different textfile based on user's username?

Tags: discord.py

I've tried on making a command to send a different .txt file in dm each time different based on the user's username. Like if the user uses the command twice they would get the same file. How can I toggle this based on user's username? I did something similar to this but in normal python with "" and I don't know what is the `username` tag to get the user's username. Can someone help me because I'm kinda beginner on discord.py

Thanks if you do :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not base it on `username`, the unique key is [user.id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.id). The username can change over time.

Bur if you want, you can get the username with this command: [user.name](http://%20%20https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.name)

Comment: So you can like use this:
`@bot.command()`
`async def data(ctx):`
  `if user.id == "608575327811272704":` (my userid)
     `await ctx.reply("Hi VDP!")
    `else:`
     `await ctx.reply("Unknown ID!")`

Comment: In a command you get the user who sent it with `ctx.author` (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author) and its `id` is of type `int`, so no `""` needed